# How do I get the Gallio MSBuild task to find my specific Gallio executables

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, gallio

I am trying to get Gallio to be called from MSBuild in a TeamCity build configuration.  The Agent/Server for TeamCity does not have Gallio installed but I do have a distribution of Gallio in my source tree.  I am using MSBuild to do the actual build of the project.

How can I tell the Gallio task to use the Gallio executables that are in the source tree?

Comment: Out of curiosity: What is the reason for not installing Gallio on the server?

Comment: It's on the codebetter.com teamcity server ... they're kind enough to open up hosting for OSS projects without others pestering them to install this or that piece of software for their specific build.  Besides it makes the builds more portable to do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you need your equivalent of the following tag.

```
<UsingTask AssemblyFile="C:\Program Files\Gallio\bin\Gallio.MSBuildTasks.dll" TaskName="Gallio" />
```

Place it in the main Project tag.

Colin